# Erroneous Help Page (incorrect location provided)

Tags: bug, help-center

On the [Talk in Chat Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) page in the stackoverflow.com help center, the following is stated:

> Where is chat?
>
> There is a link to chat in the footer of every page, as well as in the Stack Exchange site switcher menu (top *left* corner of the page).

The "Stack Exchange site switcher menu" is located at the top *right*, not the top *left*.

Comment: It is in top left of all SE sites _except_ SO because of the new navigation bar

Comment: It would be a kindness to include the icon image so readers would know what they should be looking for when trying to find  the 'site switcher menu'?  It would also be helpful if the SO differences were explicitly mentioned on this help page?